# GIMP controls, icons too small

Tags: windows-10, gimp

I recently installed the latest GIMP for Windows 10: GIMP 2.10.20 (revision 1)

The controls and icons are very small, to the point that they're hard to read. Is there a way to make them bigger?

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Edit/Preferences/Interface/Theme*. Note the path of your current theme and open that folder using File Explorer. Edit the gtkrc file and paste this at the bottom of the file:

```
style "user-font"
{
    font_name="Segoe UI 12"
}
widget_class "*" style "user-font"
```

(Change the font name and size according to your preference)

Comment: This doesn't work as written because it's highly likely that this file is not user editable.  Users will need to run an editor as administrator in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`Edit > Preferences > Interface > Icon Theme > Custom icon size` lets you increase the size of many(but not all) icons.

For the text, this is under the control of the UI "theme".

So, figure out which theme you are using (`Edit > Preferences > Interface > Themes`), and make a private copy (see edit `Preferences > Folders > Themes` for the directories that contains the standard themes and your private themes).

Once you have a copy of your theme, edit the `gtkrc` file in it (his is  a plain text file), and near the beginning you can find two places where you can change the font name and size:

```
gtk-font-name = "Noto Sans Mono 14"

# KDE hack to match gtk/gnome defaults
gtk-button-images = 0

style "tlsog-default-style"
{
#  font_name = "Noto Sans Mono 14"
```

Your file possibly has `"Sans 10"` as the font name.

All other font specs in the file are just size changes from that, so you don't need to change more than these two lines (and in fact only the one which isn't commented in your file).

Comment: My version shows a slightly different dialog: Edit>Preferences>Interface>Icon Theme>Custom Icon Size. When I set the size to Huge, the largest setting, the icons are still quite small. I have the feeling the designers were working with huge standalone monitors. I'm working on a laptop.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work for me, either. I'm on GIMP 2.10.30 and the icons are unreadable.

Comment: This works, but the UI is pants (you can't click "huge", you have to drag a control so it is in the same horiztontal position as the word "huge"), and "huge" is only "still very small, just about big enough to see".  Also, not directly mentioned in the question, but this doesn't address "text" at all.

Comment: @SomeoneElse See augmented answer for the text size change

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have display scaling issues. Are you using a monitor (maybe 4k?) that has windows scaling set over 100? Even for just full HD it is common. If so, change the scaling to 100% and set your screen resolution to max (native) to test this. Pressing control and scrolling up/down also works in some places depending on where this sizing is an issue. Gimp does not normally play well with scaling set other than 100%. Newer updates perform better, but is still buggy.

Comment: Are you assuming I'm working with a large standalone monitor? I'm working on a laptop. Where on Windows 10 would I access the settings you're referring to, assuming they would apply to a laptop?

Comment: I was on a laptop too, it wouldn't matter I think.  https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.windowscentral.com/how-change-high-dpi-settings-classic-apps-windows-10-april-2018-update%3famp       To directly change screen DPI to 100%, see https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/118914d1485629514-change-dpi-scaling-level-displays-windows-10-a-dpi_in_settings-1.png?s=d1283a231d65cb2e53913a737abce389

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (prompted by space42's answer) was to set the default theme via "Edit/Preferences/Interface/Theme" to "system".  Text is still small, but it is now at least visible.

You can also edit the theme's "gtkrc" file (as discussed in the other answers).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Edit > Preferences > Interface > Icon Theme > Change the drop down to "Custom Size" and drag the tab below that.